# usage of mpich2 (hydra, tcp/ip) on servers with several network cards

Tags: mpi, mpich

I want to use MPICH2 MPI library on unusual network configuration of three servers:

```
             /-------------------------------\
server1 has eth0 and eth1                    |
                      |                      |
server2 has          eth2 and eth3           |
                               |             |
server3 has                   eth4 and eth5 -/
```

Only pairs of eth0-eth5; eth1-eth2; eth3-eth4 are connected. In every pair there is a different ip subnetwork.

Can I setup MPICH2 with nemesis & tcp; PM is hydra to use such configuration of network?

Note, that I can't setup bridged networking between eth0 and eth1 on server1 or between eth2 and eth3 on server2; this is limitation of my eth driver.